# requirejs returns "undefined" when requiring("elasticsearch")

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, require

I am using Grunt / Bower / Define / Require. So far I could require every library without problmens (e.g. Backbone).
However require always returns undefined for elasticsearch.
Elastic search is a node module loaded with Bower.

I tried different define/require notation, passing arguments to the callback, or passing require to the callback. 
I also tried elasticsearch, elastisearch.min and elasticsearch.jquery with not luck.

Any suggestion?

Search.js

```
define(
[
"elasticsearch",
"backbone"
],
function () {
    console.log(require("elasticsearch")); // prints "undefined"
    console.log(require("backbone")); // prints object
});
```

Main.js

```
require.config({
waitSeconds: 60,
paths: {
    jquery: "../components/jquery/dist/jquery.min",
    underscore: "../components/underscore/underscore-min",
    backbone: "../components/backbone/backbone",
    elasticsearch: "../components/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.min"
}
});

define(["app"], function () {
});
```

Comment: Elastic search is proper module or its legacy global? see http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-shim

Comment: Its the bower package.

Comment: I maneged to get elastic search to work using this snippet:
`var client = new $.es.Client({
      hosts: 'localhost:9200'
    });`

https://github.com/elastic/bower-elasticsearch-js

require still returns undefined though.